# Soma incompleta com JOINS no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma duvida há alguns dias e não consigo achar uma solução.

Possuo as tabelas:

**balanco**

```
+------------+---------+------------+----------+
| id_balanco | id_loja |    data    | dinheiro |
+------------+---------+------------+----------+
|          1 |       1 | 2019-01-01 | 100.00   |
|          2 |       1 | 2019-01-02 | 25.00    |
|          3 |       1 | 2019-02-01 | 50.00    |
|          4 |       1 | 2019-02-02 | 50.00    |
+------------+---------+------------+----------+
```

**balanco_cartoes**

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
| id | id_balanco | id_cartao | valor  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |         2 | 100.00 |
|  2 |          2 |         1 | 50.00  |
|  3 |          3 |         3 | 50.00  |
|  4 |          4 |         3 | 50.00  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
```

**balanco_despesas**

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
| id | id_balanco | descricao | valor  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | Água      | 100.00 |
|  2 |          2 | Luz       | 50.00  |
|  3 |          3 | Diversos  | 50.00  |
|  4 |          4 | Diversos  | 50.00  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
```

**balanco_fornecedores**

```
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
| id | id_balanco | id_cartao | valor  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |         1 | 100.00 |
|  2 |          2 |         4 | 50.00  |
|  3 |          3 |         3 | 50.00  |
|  4 |          4 |         3 | 50.00  |
+----+------------+-----------+--------+
```

Com essa tabelas preciso fazer uma consulta com os totais de cada mês de uma loja e para todas as lojas (ok, aqui acredito que seja só remover o `id` do `where`). O que eu tenho tentado é isso:

```
SELECT data, SUM(dinheiro) AS dinheiro, cartao, despesas, fornecedores
FROM balanco b
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_balanco, SUM( valor ) AS cartao FROM balanco_cartoes GROUP BY id_balanco ) BC USING( id_balanco )
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_balanco, SUM( valor ) AS despesas FROM balanco_despesas GROUP BY id_balanco ) BD USING( id_balanco )
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id_balanco, SUM( valor ) AS fornecedores FROM balanco_fornecedores GROUP BY id_balanco ) BF USING( id_balanco )
WHERE id_loja = ? GROUP BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data) DESC, MONTH(data) DESC
```

O problema é que essa consulta soma direito apenas a coluna `dinheiro` que está na primeira tabela, nas demais tabelas ele pega apenas a primeira linha, sem soma.

O resultado que estou obtendo:

```
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
|    data    | dinheiro | cartao | despesas | fornecedores |
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 2019-02-01 | 100.00   | 50.00  | 50.00    | 50.00        |
| 2019-01-01 | 125.00   | 100.00 | 100.00   | 100.00       |
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
```

O que eu gostaria de obter:

```
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
|    data    | dinheiro | cartao | despesas | fornecedores |
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
| 2019-02-01 | 100.00   | 100.00 | 100.00   | 100.00       |
| 2019-01-01 | 125.00   | 150.00 | 150.00   | 150.00       |
+------------+----------+--------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta vincular as tabelas pelo `id_balanco` e utilizar um `GROUP BY` pelo mês e ano utilizando o `SUM` para somar os valores de cada tabela:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(b.data,'%m-%Y') AS mes,
       SUM(b.dinheiro) AS dinheiro,
       SUM(bc.valor) AS cartao,
       SUM(bd.valor) AS despesas,
       SUM(bd.valor) AS fornecedores
  FROM balanco b
  LEFT JOIN balanco_cartoes bc ON bc.id_balanco = b.id_balanco
  LEFT JOIN balanco_despesas bd ON bd.id_balanco = b.id_balanco
  LEFT JOIN balanco_fornecedores bf ON bf.id_balanco = b.id_balanco
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(b.data,'%m-%Y')
```

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bUWhPasuuH8E6XSPfCNY1F/0)

Comment: O vinculo do `id_balanco` já está sendo feito com `USING`

Comment: @RobertodeCampos complicando a `query` e realizando o `SUM` em `subqueries`, o que é muito pesado. O ideal seria usar dessa forma que mostrei. Se você colocar isso em um plano de execução vai notar que é muito mais performático

Comment: Concordo, só comentei que o filtro por `id_balanco` já estava sendo feito, inclusive já tem meu +1

Comment: Muito obrigado a ambos pela força.
Olhando as respostas de ambos consegui perceber o que eu estava entendendo errado.